# Reading input file and creating new hash

Tags: perl

My input files have percentage exposures and I read in only the highest value.

I keep getting errors

> odd number of elements in anonymous hash

and

> Can't use string as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

I tried forcing the numbers to be read in as integers but fell flat. Any advice? I'd like to create a hash with key and highest value.

```
    while ( <$DATA_FILE> ) {

        chomp;
        my @line_values = split( /,/, $_ );
        my $state_id    = $line_values[0];

        # skip header row
        next if ( $state_id eq $HEADER_VALUE );

        for ( @line_values ) {
            tr/%%//d
        };

        # assign data used as hash keys to variables
        my $var1 = int( $line_values[1] );
        my $var2 = int( $line_values[2] );

        if ( $var1 > $var2 ) {
            %report_data = ( { $state_id } => { \@$var1 } )
        }
        else {
            %report_data = ( { $state_id } => { \@$var2 } )
        }

    } # end while

    print \%report_data;

    # close file
    close( $DATA_FILE ) || printf( STDERR "Failed to close $file_path\n" );
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some input data and expected output?

Comment: I've attempted to fix the indentation in your sample code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Clear indentation is an important tool for understanding the structure of code and if you're asking a group of strangers to read and understand your code it's only polite to make that as easy for them as possible. It seems that your `# end while` comment is incorrect as it actually marks the end of your `for` loop. You might want to check that.

Comment: And now I've largely undone my fixes as I see your code was correct in the original version. If you're going to write one-line for loops, it might be clearer to use the postfix version - `tr/%%//d for @line_values`. But you may well be misunderstanding `tr/.../.../` as that second `%` isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: Oh, and you have a spurious, closing, `}`. Not sure where that came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without any indication of what the input and expected output should be, but at a guess your `if` blocks should look like this

```
if ( $var1 > $var2 ) {
    $report_data{$state_id} = $var1;
}
else {
    $report_data{$state_id} = $var2;
}
```

or, more simply

```
$report_data{$state_id} = $var1 > $var2 ? $var1 : $var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the culprit:

```
%report_data = ({$state_id} => {\@$var1})
```

{ } creates a hashref. You are doing two weird things in this line: use a hashref with a single key ($state_id) as the key in %report_data and a hashref with a single key (`\@$var1`, which tries to derefence the scalar $var1 and use it in array context (`@$var1`) and then tries to turn that into a reference again (I'm confused, no wonder the interpreter is as well) ).
That'd make more sense as

```
%report_data = ($state_id => $var1);
```

But that would reset the hash %report_data for every line you read.
What you want is to just set the key of that hash, so first, define the variable before the loop:

```
my %report_data = ();
```

and in your while loop, just set a key to a value:

```
$report_data{ $state_id } = $var1; # or $var2
```

Finally, you are trying to print a reference to the hash, which makes little sense. I'd suggest a simple loop:

```
for my $key (keys %report_data) {
    print $key . " = " . $report_data{ $key } . "\n";
}
```

This iterates over all the keys in the hash and then prints them with their values, and looks easy to read and understand, I hope.

In general: don't try to use references unless you know how they work. They are not a magic bullet that you fire at your code and all the problems go poof; quite the opposite, they can become that painful bullet that ends up in your own foot. It's good to learn about references, though, because you will need them when you advance and work more with Perl. [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) is a good place to start.